# Creating a back link using Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii

I need to know how to create a back link in the action view of the Yii Framework.

I want to use `CHtml::link('Back',Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);` but this somehow just does not want to work?

Quite new to this Framework.

Answer (score 7):

If I test it, i didn't see the "Back"-Text. :(

-> But, if you want see the link, just use "echo" before CHtml:

```
echo CHtml::link('Back',Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
```

That works fine. :)

Comment: It works but it goes back one step only. Doesnt go back more.